# Exporting an Access database with values from lookup tables

Tags: excel, ms-access, export, lookup-tables

Client is interested in getting data from an Access database in an Excel spreadsheet.  This would ordinarily be as simple as going to the Export menu for the table.

This database includes several lookup tables (shown as pulldown menus on the UI form).  These values are not represented in the main table as usable text.  Also, the drop downs allow multiple choices.

For example,

> **customer_data** - customer demographic info.
>
> **lookup_car** - stores car descriptions (Pinto, Vega, Reliant Robin, Mustang, Corvette)
>
> **junction_car_customer** - joins a customer with one or more cars

Customer Jeremy Clarkson (cust_id: 1) owns three cars.  The dropdown for his record shows:

```
Pinto (car_id=100)
Reliant Robin (car_id=101)
Vega (car_id=102)
```

The junction_car_customer data looks like this:

```
cust_id    car_id
1          100
1          101
1          102
```

Is there a relatively painless way of exporting to Excel, and having data from the drop downs (values from `lookup_car` joined in `junction_car_customer`) placed in a cell as character-separated values?

Comment: Is it possible to create a report that will show this information?  You're really talking about a simple left join query, and you should just export the results of the query rather than the actual tables.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I neglected to consider this.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll give you some rep points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to create a report that will show this information? You're really talking about a simple left join query, and you should just export the results of the query rather than the actual tables.